# javascript/nativescript - remove duplicates by id but update other property

Tags: javascript, nativescript, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects, so lets say that at certain point i have this:

```
{
    {
        "subTitulo": "Salmon",
        "mainImage": "/img/thumbt49eEUtB1zgFj41L.png",
        "preco": "11",
        "id": 22,
        "quantidade": 2
    },
    {
        "subTitulo": "Salmon",
        "mainImage": "/img/thumbt50eEltB1zgFj41i.png",
        "preco": "11",
        "id": 22,
        "quantidade": 4
    }
}
```

It´s a takeaway app, and the array above is when the user is in the final view of the app, and i can remove the duplicates using this:

```
const filteredArr = gotData.ordersFinal.reduce((acc, current) => {
        const x = acc.find(item => item.id === current.id);
        if (!x) {
            return acc.concat([current]);
        } else {
            return acc;
        }
    }, []);
```

when the user FIRST goes to the final view and there is duplicates everything works fine, but lets supose that the user goes back and needs to change the quantity(quantidade) and then goes AGAIN to the final view, what is happening is that the property quantidade is not updated and i understand why, because it´s a duplicate of id, so it stays with the one already have.

My question is, how do i remove the duplicates but update the property quantidade with the last one?

Thanks for your time, regards

Comment: What do you mean by user goes back? What is done programmatically at that point? Explain further please.

Comment: goes back to the view where he increments the quantidade property or decreases it, it´s a listview with food and there are buttons + and - in each type of food, and then after making the desire changes he hits the kart button on the top right corner and goes to the final view.

Comment: does she uses browser buttons to go back?

Comment: no, its a mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a timestamp to each element added to the shopping list such as

```js
item.timeAdded = new Date().valueOf();
```

and at the final view you can check the items by this timeAdded and use the latest value for the quantity as the updated one. Such as;

```js
const filteredArr = gotData.ordersFinal.reduce((acc, current) => {
    const x = acc.find(item => item.id === current.id);
    if (!x) {
        return acc.concat([current]);
    } else {
        if(current.timeAdded > x.timeAdded) // this was added later
            x.quantidade = current.quantidade // update the quantity
        let index = acc.findIndex(item => item.id === current.id)
        acc[index] = x // update the accumulator
        return acc;
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: on else, and then inside if(item ... it´s saying that item is not defined

Comment: because there is no item :D sorry, let me check the code again.

Comment: Hey!!! it´s working beautifully!, thank you some much for your solution, i just made a change, instead of using timeAdded i actually used the quantidade property because the user might want 3 salmon for example but then he remebers he just wants 1 and because of that instead of if(current.quantidade > x.quantidade) i used this if(current.quantidade != x.quantidade)...thanks again, i really aprecciate your help. regards